# Java: Array Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer:  ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int x = sc.nextInt();
int lArray = x - 2;
int[] newArray = new int[lArray];

System.out.println("Let's display all possible integers...");
for (int i = 0; i <= newArray.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = i + 2;
    System.out.print(newArray[i] + " ");
}
```

I've just started Java recently, but I sure that if I coded similarly in another language, I would face the same problem.  This is an excerpt from an application where it lists all the prime numbers up until the user's input.

The reason why x-2 is used as the definition of lArray is because the length of the array will be all the integers from 2 until the number {2, 3, 4, 5... x}.

I noticed that for the line

```
for (int i = 0; i <= newArray.length; i++) {
```

if I change `i <= newArray` to `i < newArray`, the code works without error.  However, the user's input, x, is left out which is a problem if x is prime.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `<` and not `<=` in:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= newArray.length; i++)
                  ^^
```

If `foo` any array, valid index of `foo` are `[0,foo.length-1]`

Using `foo.length` as an index will cause `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.

And also `lArray` which contains number of natural numbers `<=x` but excluding only ***one*** number `1`, its value should be `x-1` and not `x-2`.

Answer (score 5):

Change the array length to `(x - 1)` instead, and go with the `<` condition, which you've already found is necessary to avoid the out-of-bounds exception.

The reason you need an array that is 1 element larger than what you're currently using is because there are `(n - 1)` candidates that must be considered between 2 and n , not `(n - 2)`.

For example, there are two candidates less than or equal to three (2 and 3), both of which, coincidentally, happen to be prime.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= newArray.length; i++) //should be <, not <=
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
int lArray = x - 1;
```

And change your condition to use `<` instead of `<=`.

In Java as in C/C++, arrays are ZERO based. So your array of **N** values will go from index **0** to **N-1**.

Taking your example: `{2, 3, 4, 5... x}`.

You will need `N-1` values to store all positive numbers but **1** in an integer array. So, if `N` equals to **4**, your array will be:

```
newArray[0] = 2;
newArray[1] = 3;
newArray[2] = 4;
```

Hence, array lenght must be **3** (**N-1**).