# 2D Array Index Out of Bounds Exception issue

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a program to generate a schedule; I've gotten it to accept user input for who the employees are by adding them to a list, but when I try to move the items from the list to the double array, I get an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception. What can I do here to solve this issue, I've tried about everything else I can think of.

```
import java.util.*;

public class schedule
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner readme = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> employees = new ArrayList<String>();
        //accepts input for list
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Employees are: " + employees);
            System.out.println("Are there more? (y/n)");
            if (readme.next().startsWith("y"))
            {
                System.out.println("Who?");
                employees.add(readme.next());
            }
            else
            {
                //creates a double array the size of the employees list by the number of shifts in the week
                String[][] scheduleArr = new String[employees.size()][14];
                //adds items from array to corresponding spot on double array
                for (int i = 0; i <= scheduleArr.length; i++)
                {
                    scheduleArr[i][0] = employees.get(i);
                }
                System.out.print(scheduleArr[0][0]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is this obvious duplicate upvoted 3 times(at least)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Array Index Out of Bounds Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951252/java-array-index-out-of-bounds-exception)

Answer (score 2):

Array indices start at 0 and end at length - 1.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= scheduleArr.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < scheduleArr.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate from 0 to `length-1` not `length` (arrays are 0 based)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < scheduleArr.length; i++) //NOT i <= scheduleArr.length
        {
            scheduleArr[i][0] = employees.get(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < scheduleArr.length; i++) //NOT i <= scheduleArr.length
        {
            scheduleArr[i][0] = employees.get(i);
        }
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= scheduleArr.length; i++) //NOT i <= scheduleArr.length
        {
            scheduleArr[i][0] = employees.get(i);
        }
```

Both will do the need for you!